# Value of type 'Viewcontroller' has no member

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm writing a code to send a pin code by email. However, an error occurs in the process of push data. No member error occurs when email is written and sent to emailTxtField.How do I solve this error? I'm not sure what VC.email means. The error occurs at vc.mail = emailTxtField.text!

```
    private func bindViewModel() {
        let input = SendEmailViewModel.Input(email: emailTxtField.rx.text.orEmpty.asDriver(),
                                             doneTap: nextBtn.rx.tap.asDriver())
        let output = viewModel.transform(input: input)

        output.isEnable.drive(nextBtn.rx.isEnabled).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
        output.result.emit(onNext: { [unowned self] _ in
            print("error")
            nextBtn.isEnabled = true
        }, onCompleted: {[unowned self] in pushData()}
        ).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
    
    func pushData() {
        guard let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pinCode") as? VerificationViewController else { return }
        vc.email = emailTxtField.text!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: This means that `VerificationViewController` does not have a property called `email`.

Comment: A property is something like `var email: String = ""`